# QGIS expression "get_feature" will not evaluate feature, when called within "is_selected"

Tags: qgis, expression

I have an expression `get_feature('Schools', 'INST_NO', "schoolid")` which returns a feature, as intended:

[image]

However, I want to test if the feature is currently selected. So, I have created this expression `is_selected(get_feature('Schools', 'INST_NO', "schoolid"), 'Schools')`
Which looks just like the example given in the help text for *is_selected*. 
However, this does not work; it throws the error **Eval Error: Cannot convert to feature**:

[image]

Comment: Please open issues in the QGIS repository:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: I didn't know it was a documentation issue, but now that this has been confirmed by the accepted answer, I have created a GitHub issue at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36983

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be an error in the documentation. The syntax must be: *is_selected([layer=current layer][, feature=current feature])*.

Try: `is_selected('Schools', get_feature('Schools', 'INST_NO', "schoolid"))`

---

Source: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/1475

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works. I have submitted a GitHub issue to have the documentation updated at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36983