# QGIS show only selected polygons on the map

Tags: qgis, select

I would like to make visible only these polygons, which are selected right now.

I tried to go with this hint:

[Displaying only selected features on map in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111784/displaying-only-selected-features-on-map-in-qgis)

but when in my expression I applied:

```
   is_selected('Preferred cell radius')
```

I got an error:

**Cannot convert to feature**

[image]

I tried to solve it by looking at this issue:

[QGIS expression "get_feature" will not evaluate feature, when called within "is_selected"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363873/qgis-expression-get-feature-will-not-evaluate-feature-when-called-within-is)

by adding up three columns from my data attribute table:

```
   is_selected("Preferred cell radius", get_feature("Name", "descriptio", "new_name"))
```

but in this case, I have another error:

**Eval error: Column 'Preferred cell radius' not found**

There is also another option in the Atlas features

[QGIS Atlas: Only Show Selected Feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232726/qgis-atlas-only-show-selected-feature)

but it looks like I have to add the certain feature ID

How can I make only these items visible, which are already selected?

From the answer below I have situation soch as this:

I have selected an object by the attribute table. Now instead of the style defined with `is_selected()` I have the selection color set in the project. How to apply the individual style for this selection?

[image]

Comment: Does your layer have a column named "Preferred cell radius"?

Comment: Having the selection highlight is unavoidable when using `is_selected()`. If you selected your features using an expression, use that expression as a filter in the rule and the features will keep whatever symbology you apply to the rule (rather than using the expression to make a selection).

Answer (score 5):

`is_selected()` expects a feature as input: `is_selected(<the_feature>)`. If left empty, it uses the current feature, you could also write as `is_selected($currentfeature)`. You can also reference a layer: `is_selected(<the_layer>,<the_feature>)`

You give a string `'Preferred cell radius'` or a field `"Preferred cell radius"` to it, thats where these errors come from. Either use it as:

```
is_selected()
```

or

```
is_selected(layer,get_feature(layer,attribute,value))
```

In your case the first option combined with a rule based symbology should do it. If the features are related to another layer you do the selection in, the second one should be what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, the formula works, but the result is not necessary. How about not selecting features at the same time?

Comment: See my question updated

Comment: You cannot avoid that. Selected is selected. You cannot select and not select a feature at the same time. What you can do is changing the color/style for a selection in Settings -> Options -> Canvas & Legend -> Selection color. Maybe this makes your symbology obsolete at the same time.

Comment: I would like to have the selection color synchronized with my symbology. Is it possible?