# QGIS Print Layout expression for selected features in project

Tags: labeling, print-composer, expression, select-by-expression

I have a selected feature in the project that is symbolised differently. I can see it in the print layout, but the is_selected expression returns a false. I need to label only this feature in a text box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use *is_selected*  as part of an if statement, it might do what you need.
[image]

If you want to see the other labels also - have a 2nd layer with labels, no symbols.  Set the main (is selected test) label placement to high priority.  This is what you will get:
[image]

Comment: It works in the project labeling. In my case however, all labels must show. I need a text box in the print layout that must only show the selected features' attribute/s. I tried the same expression under 'insert/edit expression' button, but no luck. Must I use it in combination with a print command?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if the edits to the answer I did will work for you.

Comment: this is an answer to your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/363879/7849